# VLC - how do I see video file's information? (resolution, encoding information etc)

Tags: vlc-media-player

How can I check video file's information from VLC?
I want to see the movies' resolution(weather 1080p or 720p, or whatever), encoding information, encoded time etc.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

you click on *Tools* and then *Media Information*:

[image]

you can also press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

On Mac, it's under *Window* and then *Media Information*.  You can press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

On either OS, be sure to look under the Codec Details tab for resolution information.

Comment: Make sure to check the **Codec Details** tab for additional information.

Comment: On Mac it's under `Window`->`Media Information` or hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: This answer is useless without mentioning the Code Details and we can get to the Code Details directly using Ctrl+J. The answer is the "Resolution" in the Code Details.

Comment: @user34660 hit the "edit button" and improve the answer.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to get this information to show in the "Detailed List" playlist view mode?

Answer (score 30):

On Mac it is located at:
 Window Menu, - Media Information

[image]